# Wake up the the application when bluetooth connects to my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I want to build a application that interacts with my BT device and wakes him.

I want to know is it possible for my application to get notified every time the device asks for connection. Take into consideration that the application is not active.

For example, when i get into the car it connects automatically to my car BT and when i get call, the call application is activated? (but maybe that's something that iOS internally does...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for applications to catch such events in the background mode. While in the background the app is completely paused (except for some special cases) and can't catch anything at all.

Comment: Is there any other way to make it happen?